# IntelliJ - Running 2 classes via Gherkin Language

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gherkin

I wrote two java classes in IntelliJ software. To run each class I have a .feature file where I write the command to run my class. For example, for a database class I write:

Feature: name_of_class

Scenario: Name of the Scenario

- Given I connect to "Name_of_class"
- When I run "Method in my class"
- Then I execute operation "another method with an assertion"

How can run two classes (one after another)? Should I write a new third class that calls the methods of the first two classes? Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to share more details for a proper answer.

Details that would be good to know is if you are using a package manager like Maven or if you don't.

Let me assume that you are in a situation where you are able to run a JUnit test.

What you need to do in that situation is to have a [runner class](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton/blob/master/src/test/java/skeleton/RunCukesTest.java) that will run Cucumber-JVM. It is a JUnit class that doesn't have any methods and that is executed with a special Cucumber runner. It will find your feature files as well as your step classes if they are located in the same package, or a subpackage, relative to the package where the runner class lives.

Another approach to get started may to clone, or download a copy, of the [Cucumber Java Skeleton](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton) and run it. It can be executed in three different ways, two of them with a build system like Maven or Gradle.

If this feels like an aswer that you don't understand, please tell us and we might be able to give a better answer.